# Firebug catches event, jQuery doesn't?

Tags: jquery, firebug, jquery-events

This is weird.

On Firebug I select this `<span>` element and check Register Events. Clicking gives me this:

```
mousedown clientX=550, clientY=591 » span
mouseup clientX=550, clientY=591 » span
click clientX=550, clientY=591 » span
```

But this doesn't log anything:

```
$('span').click(function() {
    console.log('click');
});
```

neither does this:

```
$('.parent-element').on('click', 'span', function() {
    console.log('click');
});
```

What gives?

EDIT:
The span element is created dynamically from a jQuery plugin, the rendered is this:

```
<div class="col-r">
    <label class="chk-label-active" for="lbl-">Selecionar</label>
    <div class="customForm-unselectable chk-area chk-checked">
        <span></span>
    </div>
    <input id="lbl-" class="customForm-hidden" type="checkbox">
</div>
```

I've also tried to attach the `onClick` element to `.chk-area` still no luck

Comment: Your html? Any errors shown anywhere? A [JS Fiddle](http://jsFiddle.net/) to reproduce your problem?

Comment: Are you using `$(document).ready`? Is the `span` dynamically generated?

Comment: Edited to show some html. The span element is dynamic, but it's parents are also not working.

Comment: Have you tried attaching the event handling to the highest element which is not dynamically created?

Comment: Well, there's the problem. Your span is empty, so it should have zero width. How Firebug thinks it was clicked on is a mystery to me.

Comment: @DaDaDom, yes, I've tried `$('.col-r').on('click','.chk-area', function())` etc. .col-r is static and .chk-area is dynamic. Still nothing.

Comment: Please try to replicate your issue on JS Fiddle or JSBIN